# Please help me decipher the symbols in this closed-form

Tags: algorithms

I want to implement the algorithm [provided in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1106968):

[image]

(Please see original post for details.)

It calculates every combination of making a provided amount by using coins from a provided list of denominations.

I think I have a pretty good grasp of what the algorithm does and I understand that it's a Union, but I'm struggling with the exact meaning of the asterisk `*`, the multiplication symbol `×` and the comma `,`.

Comment: The asterisk is normal multiplication ($j$ is how many coins of $first(J)$ you take), $\times$ is the cartesian product, interpret the left hand side as a set with one element (the rhs $C(\_,\_)$ returns a set), basically we prepend $j \cdot first(J)$ to every tuple. Also int the second argument of $C$: $J first(J)$ is probably supposed to be $J \backslash \{ first(J) \}$.